# throttle implementation using pure java script adding and removing event listener

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement throttle function in vanilla java script. I have seen other implementations on the web, but the way I have implemented it is more understandable for myself. I was wondering if any of you experts can take a look and let me know if I am missing some thing. It seems to be working fine but I am not sure the way I handle it is the correct.

here is the html code :

```
<html>

  <head>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div id='move'>

    </div>
    <div id='result'>

    </div>
  </body>
```

here is the js code

```
var area;
var result;

function init() {
  area = document.querySelector('#move');
  area.addEventListener('mousemove', trottle);
  result = document.querySelector('#result');
}

function updateResult(event) {
  let xCordinate = event.clientX;
  let yCordinate = event.clientY;
  result.textContent = `${xCordinate} , ${yCordinate}`;
}



function trottle(event) {
  updateResult(event);
  let element = event.target
  element.removeEventListener('mousemove', trottle);
  setTimeout(function() {
    element.addEventListener('mousemove', trottle);
  }, 2000)

}

init();
```

Comment: Questions like this regarding working code are better asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. This site is for code that isn't working

Comment: Most `throttle` implementations are pure javascript. Which one did you read?